# change screen resolution without clicking resolution on desktop or using graphics card settings

Tags: graphics-card, windows-explorer, resolution

How can I change screen resolution without using Explorer.exe or my graphics card settings.

Both crash every time I try.

Comment: even if you boot into safe mode?

Comment: Nice idea.  I think it still wouldn't work because I may have a very strange graphics card problem.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your graphics card driver?

Comment: It worked.  If you add that as an answer, you'll get the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely, you have a bad/incorrect driver installed.  However, here is a [program](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Quick-Resolution-Changer.shtml) that will let you change resolutions quickly.